# Why kafka topics receive messages and streams doesn't?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've got a complete Confluent Platform on an AKS cluster.
I'm trying to send messages inside a ksqldb stream, but the messages arrive only on the topic.
This is how I created the stream

```
"CREATE STREAM PROVA (ID STRING KEY, NUM INTEGER) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic_prova', KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

and this is the code that sends messages

```
const KsqldbClient = require("ksqldb-client");
const options = {
    host: "http://ksqldb.ckafka.svc.cluster.local",
    port: 8088,
};
const client = new KsqldbClient(options);

const asyncOperation = async () => {
    await client.connect();
    var i = 0;
    while(i<100){
        const row = {
            id: "value",
            num: 2
        };
        const {data, status, error } = await client.insertInto("PROVA", row);
        console.log(data)
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error)
        i++;
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    }
    await client.disconnect();
};

asyncOperation();
```

Here the logs:

```
{ rows: [ { seq: 0, status: 'ok' } ] }
200
undefined
```

The topic receives the messages, like shown here.
[image]

I don't know how to resolve it, even because i need streams later to aggregate data.

Comment: Ideally, you use Kafkajs, not ksql client

Comment: It's the same thing. I even tried to create a nodejs producer with kafkajs but the result is the same: the topic contains the message but the stream is blank

Comment: You can create a processing log on a self hosted ksqlDB Cluster - take a look here - https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/processing-log/

Comment: "but the stream is blank" - Did you forget to set `auto.offset.reset=earliest` in ksql?